# C# Brickbreaker game, get brick to dissapear when hit

Tags: c#

I have an array for the x co-ordinate of the bricks, an array for the y co-ordinates of the bricks and an array to show weather it is visible. My code reads like this:

```
            if (Visible[0] == 1)
            {
                paper.DrawRectangle(pen, BrickX[0], BrickY[0], 50, 10);
            }
```

and for my collision for the ball to hit the brick, the code reads:

```
        if (Visible[0] == 1)
        {
            if ((x >= BrickX[0]) && (x <= BrickX[0] + 50))
            {

                if ((y >= picDisplayBat.Height - 190) && (y <= BrickY[0] + 10))
                    yChange = -yChange;
                    Visible[0] = 0;
```

This does not seem to work as when the ball comes close the brick, the brick dissapears before the collision has happened and the ball goes straight through it. any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing brackets around your second if test.

Regardless of the outcome of the test the brick gets set to invisible. Your code is effectively this:

```
if ((y >= picDisplayBat.Height - 190) && (y <= BrickY[0] + 10))
{
    yChange = -yChange;
}
Visible[0] = 0;
```

You want this:

```
if ((y >= picDisplayBat.Height - 190) && (y <= BrickY[0] + 10))
{
    yChange = -yChange;
    Visible[0] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I won't answer your question exactly, but this might help.*

It's kind of unobvious what your code does now. Why always `[0]`?

Just create a **class** called `Brick` and a **class** called `Ball`:

```
class Brick {
   public double x, y;
   public double size;
   public bool visible;
};

class Ball {
   public double x, y;
   public double size;
};
```

Now introduce the member in the `Brick` called `bool Intersects(Ball ball)`, which yields `true` if the ball intersects with the brick *(you could simply check this by their bounding boxes).*

Now your checks become extremely simple (I assume you have an array of bricks somewhere called `bricks`).

```
foreach (Brick brick in bricks) {
   if (brick.visible && brick.Intersects(ball)) {
      // Hide the brick
      brick.visible = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, I think you are doing your steps out of order.

Your second routine is perhaps doing too much.  It should only determine a collision, and return an identifier for the target of the collision.  Then a consuming routine uses that information to adjust projectile trajectory (reflect it back) and finally turn-off the visibility.

By the way, collision detection is a popular venue for what is known as "[double-dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)" invocations.  Consider using the visitor pattern (ala Gang of Four) as a way to code this up.